# Can not find my Xiaomi MI 6 device in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I recently got my Xiaomi MI 6 device and wanted to test my android applications on it. Here is what I've done:

First I went into https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#Drivers
to find the OEM USB driver for my new phone but it turns out that the USB for MI 6 (MTP) was already upp to date and recognizeable for my computer.

I've enabled the debugging option on my phone.

Connected the phone with my charger/usb cable (obviously).

My phone has the latest Nougat update.

Android studio is upp to date.

adb was installed in Android SDK manager.

### And here comes the problem, when I open up android studio and press "run" my device is not found, despite having done everything above correctly. Anyone got a solution to this? Or have experienced the same thing? The emulator works, but not finding my own device.

Edit: found the solution in another post her (strangely enough i didn't find it here before the mentioning of pc suite installation, soo thank you for that hint).

Solution: just turn off "Turn on MUI optimization" in dev options. 
Good to know for those buying a new xiaomi phone, if you have the latest version of your phone (higher than mashmallow) the mi pc suite won't work/find your device. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- !!! You Don't Need Mi PC Suit !!!
- !!! JUST INSTALL ADB Interface Drivers OF YOUR RESPECTIVE DEVICE !!!

  1. Open Android Studio Application and Run A Demo Application and Stay On This Window. [image]
  2. Uninstall Device Drivers from **Device Manager**
  3. Plugin Your Device via USB to PC and Restart Your Mi Device.
  4. While Restarting Device it will actually installing and configuring device drivers
  5. When device is successfully restarted look at Device Screen, It ask to **ALLOW this app Notification**, as you allow the app it will show your device in **Select Deployment Target** Window
     [image]

Answer (score 0):

Download "Mi PC Suite" and install it.

Comment: Except for the fact hat mi pc suit doesn't work for versions higher than marshmallow what im aware of.

Comment: Did u turned on USB debugging?